# Internet explorer has stopped working. How do I debug my code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

I recently finished a pretty complex feature for my application at work. It works well in almost all major browsers. The exception is IE 11 where the browser just crashes. The console doesn't show any (serious) error:

[image]

And this is all I can see:

[image]

And no matter what I click, the browser just exits.

Since this is stackoverflow, [here's the source code](https://pastebin.com/h5uQdyhP), but my question isn't really what causes this behaviour since the code's 700 lines, but rather what can I do in this situation in order to be able to somehow debug this? Trial and error really isn't a solution in this case (CTRL+R is not an option, and opening IE, entering my credentials (no autocomplete, ofc), and going through the flow each time I change something really isn't feasible).

Any idea what I could do in this situation?

Comment: If you have Microsoft Visual Studio installed it will attempt to debug Internet Explorer - the executable file itself, not the JavaScript.

Comment: To debug the JavaScript you can add the keyword [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) into your code before the crash starts

Comment: @JohnVandivier I know, I don't wanna debug IE.... I will try with debugger, thanks. I'll post an update.

Comment: a 'crashing' web browser (pretty much) can only be caused by one of your IE Addons. The first step in troubleshooting web browser issues is to test in noAddons. Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff [url] . There should be an entry in your Events Control Panel. Start>Control Panel>Administrative tools>Event Viewer

Comment: Thanks, I tried with no addons. Same result unfortunately. This happens on any PC we've tried so far so I don't think they would influence.